# How can I use Scanner.hasNext to fill multiple array values?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a series of dice and for each one, I need to prompt the user if they'd like to reroll it or not.  The simplest way seems to be a prompt with the Scanner class- I check to see what they enter and handle appropriately.  However, scanner.next() will throw an exception if the requested data doesn't exist in the user input.  So, scanner.hasnext() needs to fit in here somehow.

This is the code I have;  it will enter the entries into the response array but will throw an exception if the user input contains neither Y nor N.

```
public Boolean[] chooseDice(int diceNum){
    Boolean[] responses = new Boolean[diceNum];
    Scanner scansworth = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0; i<diceNum; i++){
        System.out.printf("Reroll this die? (%d)\n",i);
                responses[i] = (scansworth.next("[YN]")) == "Y" ? true : false;
    }
        return responses;
```

How do I call scansworth.hasNext("[YN]") so that the intepreter doesn't lock and so that it correctly checks for entry after each step of the loop?

Comment: `the system disregarding some parts of the loop` --> What do you actually mean by this statement??

Comment: If I try to have something inside the loop that waits for hasNext to be true it will work correctly the first time and then not fire correctly the next time.  (I've tried a few different variations and don't have eclipse in front of me so it's hard to precisely explain.)

Comment: I edited the post to try to make it more obvious what I mean.

Comment: why do you need boolean array?

Comment: It gets passed to an object that rerolls the corresponding state of the dice.  It could just as easily store the results as an array of strings, but it doesn't matter

Comment: `scansworth.next("[YN]"))` --> Why are you using [YN] inside next()??

Comment: According to the documentation it will look for the next instance of the regular expression inside.

Comment: Why would you need it here.. Just use `nextLine()` and check whether input is `Y` or not..

Comment: If the input is neither Y nor N it's not correct input.

Comment: OK.. then it will be ok to use it..

Comment: It looks like if you enter something that's neither N nor Y it will accept it as false, which isn't correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surround the code reading user input with a while, to check whether a user input is in given pattern.... using `hasNext("[YN]")`.. Also, you don't need `scanner.next([YN])`.. Just use `next()`.. It will fetch you the next line entered, and you can compare it with "Y"..

```
 for (int i=0; i<diceNum; i++){
           int count = 0;
           System.out.printf("Reroll this die? (%d)\n",i);

           // Give three chances to user for correct input.. 
           // Else fill this array element with false value..

           while (count < 3 && !scansworth.hasNext("[YN]")) {
               count += 1;  // IF you don't want to get into an infinite loop
               scansworth.next();
           }    

           if (count != 3) {
                /** User has entered valid input.. check it for Y, or N **/
                responses[i] = (scansworth.next()).equals("Y") ? true : false;
           } 
           // If User hasn't entered valid input.. then it will not go in the if  
           // then this element will have default value `false` for boolean..
 }
```

Comment: why are you checking for count<3? why specifically 3? should it not be diceNum?

Comment: I am just checking it so that if hasNext() is false , it does not gets into infinite loop.. It gives 3 chances to get input for one array element.. And it is for each input..

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like this.....

```
public Boolean[] chooseDice(int diceNum){
    Boolean[] responses = new Boolean[diceNum];
    boolean isCorrect = false;
    Scanner scansworth = new Scanner(System.in);
    for (int i=0; i<diceNum; i++){

while(!isCorrect){

if((scansworth.hasNext().equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) ||  (scansworth.hasNext().equalsIgnoreCase("N")))`{



    responses[i] = scansworth.next();
    isCorrect = true;

}else{

       isCorrect = false;


    }
  }

}
```